# Issue decrypting Alexa request signature using openssl_public_decrypt

Tags: php, alexa-skills-kit, pem, php-openssl

I'm implementing a validator for [validating incoming requests from Amazon Alexa](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/developing-an-alexa-skill-as-a-web-service#checking-the-signature-of-the-request). I'm on step 5 and 6 which state:

> 5) base64-decode the Signature header value on the request to obtain the encrypted signature.
>
> 6) Use the public key extracted from the signing certificate to decrypt the encrypted signature to produce the asserted hash value.

I've managed to extract the public key from the PEM-encoded X.509 certificate by doing:

```
$publicKey = openssl_pkey_get_public($pem);
$keyData = openssl_pkey_get_details($publicKey);
```

Which returns my public key. I've then attempted to decrypt the signature like so:

```
openssl_public_decrypt(base64_decode($this->signature), $decryptedSignature, $keyData['key']);
```

Which should return me a `sha1` hash of the request body for me to compare with the actual request body, but what I get back from `$decryptedSignature` doesn't appear to be a `sha1` hash. I'm hoping I'm missing something obvious but I can't see it.

To make things a little easier, here's a real life `base64_encoded` signature header returned from Alexa's test service:

> DElCRMK3sXkhmnmu3D2HzVyuLHJ3JkABuBy2LCRX+winUhV6pSC9p1ASKFi9DzESsCyQ74izlFSvi3zECbSbT45bI38JpARJlal81YpWKxz2zTX+y6Qi+We/bFHHpU4gZO7nTTVQDWG4ua6EuWDTt3jL4B+hPOzO1OKix0jHKQldaTd9meyanttZ5QK7WotBeS6xU+Pum/dmiQ+LM39NERUCrCRyeU07PUdQt+L5PI8MehMz5ClHFOTWgyjE/J/b4zrX4weppb/KJhqQVmbw79BWMPuaSwf6BIHyf+4+/NSMmoaJ2WMKKEXf1aV7ac71QFFx9pw4P0BX7DK/hqy98Q==

And here is the public key extracted from https://s3.amazonaws.com/echo.api/echo-api-cert-4.pem:

> -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
>   MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAnK+zBruRA1TnbgQGxE+b
>   4XiTTZyDkGwJ6068AGsXQmgt9lVhC8CTTC4wdR5NXosboV6/63worQCNo412csBV
>   jUy3H1/VEs+5Kv+AiAOUuKoBfEU8zAvHCc7GmOKUgNidcDA0MSpx3ZTMSGGbkfaL
>   ikRzne6nFZ6jNOnkqTtGD6SrCIYgLNArScYoPzIcXEypHFrognzrR4Ee0YcefGZy
>   S81Yqev/lli01dAgRvpnAty68rYTmxkNhzUSG6IIbFHIxXJKAETAkGiKJcgZpfG2
>   1Ok5Dk3yGrESY/ID5OnxvMxiXSnXwht8JD6bd15ui0tPDa85B0jpZLloqQZe26oR
>   owIDAQAB
>   -----END PUBLIC KEY-----

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I've realised my mistake. The decrypted signature is returned in binary, so I need to do: `bin2hex($decryptedSignature)` in order to get the `sha1` hash. Bizarrely, the returned signature hash has 30 extra chars prepended, so the actual Alexa hash comparison needs to be:

```
public function compareHashes($pem) {

  $publicKey = openssl_pkey_get_public($pem);

  openssl_public_decrypt(base64_decode($this->signature), $decryptedSignature, $publicKey);

  $decryptedSignature = hex2bin($decryptedSignature);

  return sha1($this->responseBody) === substr($decryptedSignature, 30);
}
```

Anyway, I will open source my Alexa validation class and add a link back here once I've passed Alexa certification.

**Edit**

I'm through certification now, so here's the class I wrote for the Alexa validation: https://github.com/craigh411/alexa-request-validator

Comment: Hi, Is your skill passed certification. I'm using this library https://github.com/MayBeTall/Alexa-PHP-Endpoint/   can you help me how to do certificate verification. Plz. Thanks.

Comment: @gowri yes, my skill passed certification and I've put the validator for incoming Alexa requests up on my [github page](https://github.com/craigh411/alexa-request-validator) which you are free to use. I actually wrote this because I couldn't find any other correct implementation of the required validation; some only did arbitrary checks, some were spaghetti code (and missed certain aspects) and some didn't correctly validate the signature chain url or hashes.

Comment: Thx for reply. One more thing, shall I add that validator in all intents are only in `enters` intent. 
And I'm returning HTTP status code in all intents like `http_response_code(400)`  is this correct.